# PHPの連想配列をループさせる方法

Tags: php

二つの配列をmergeして、sumItemの値を(Item)の位置にいれてループさせたいです。
以下のforeach文でsumProductは出せるのですが、sumItemを出そうとすると失敗します。
どのように記述すれば$merge[1]の部分が以下のループ内で出てくるでしょうか？

```
<?php 
$arrA = array($t);
$arrB = array($i); 
$merge = array_merge_recursive($arrA, $arrB);
//debug($merge);?>

<?php foreach ($merge[0] as $m): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $m['User']['id']; ?></td>
      <td> (Item) </td>
      <td><?php echo $m[0]['sumProduct']; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'User' => array(
                'id' => '1'
            ),
            (int) 0 => array(
                'sumProduct' => '1'
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'User' => array(
                'id' => '2'
            ),
            (int) 0 => array(
                'sumProduct' => '2'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'User' => array(
                'id' => '1'
            ),
            (int) 0 => array(
                'sumItem' => '12'
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'User' => array(
                'id' => '2'
            ),
            (int) 0 => array(
                'sumItem' => '2'
            )
        )
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現状の `$t` `$i` の構造では array_merge_recursive を使う甲斐は薄いので

- どちらかの要素数を数えてforでループを回し、それぞれの配列にアクセスする
- `foreach($t as $key => $val)` といった形で配列のキーを取り出しながらループを回し、もう一方にアクセスするのに使う

といった方法がわかりやすいかと思います。

後者の方法を使えば、`$merge[1]` を参照することもできますが・・・

```
<?php foreach ($merge[0] as $key => $m): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $m['User']['id']; ?></td>
      <td> <?php echo $merge[1][$key][0]['sumProduct']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $m[0]['sumProduct']; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

これならマージせずに元の配列のままでいいですよね。